# Do some task before Django project stops

Tags: django, nginx, redis

How can I do some tasks like clear **Redis cache** objects before my Django project stops?  `(when I hit (Ctrl + c) in the server terminal or stop the daphne or gunicorn service)`

Is there any way to find this moment **inside** of the Django project so that there is no need for extra config and commands in the server such as **Nginx** server?